# Comparing DATETIME value with the one in previous row and selecting it if its bigger by at least 5 minutes

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I'm trying to write a query to select all rows in a table where the timestamp column's value is bigger by at least 5 minutes than the value in the previous row. My main problem is trying to get DATEDIFF function to work. In my query's current state, its throwing an error "Incorrect syntax near 'MINUTE'. Expecting '(', or SELECT".

I feel like its either a really obvious error that I can't see or I'm going about writing this query completely the wrong way. I haven't been working with SQL for very long and I'm struggling to fix this query myself so it would be great if someone could tell me where I'm going wrong or possibly how to rewrite this query in a better way.

```
SELECT temp.*
FROM   (SELECT ID, EVENT_ID, STAMP, 
               LAG(STAMP) OVER (ORDER BY STAMP) AS PREVIOUS
        FROM MyDatabase.dbo.DATA 
        WHERE EVENT_ID = $(eventNumber)) AS temp
WHERE  DATEDIFF(MINUTE, temp.STAMP, temp.PREVIOUS) >= 5
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the community. Please add more information, what kind of datatype are temp.STAMP and temp.PREVIOUS?

Comment: $(eventNumber) doesn't compile for me, is this query submitted from an environment that modifies the query before submitting it to SQL Server?

Comment: Hi, thank you for taking the time to reply. @McNets they are both datetime data types.

Comment: @Tibor Karaszi sorry I forgot to mention that I'm running an sql script from a batch script where the user types an integer for event number.

Comment: It should be `DATEDIFF(MINUTE, temp.PREVIOUS, temp.STAMP)` but that's irrelevant to the error you get. Did you try to run the same query from SSMS?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ is right you should change the order, but it is correct syntactically. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=072a2e42614786abb7ac0a8da0208952

Comment: I agree with @ypercube. I tried your query and after substituting $(eventNumber) for a number the query compiled just fine. Try it from SSMS, or catch in a trace what is *actually submitted* to SQL Server.

Comment: Could you try to change `temp`by another name?

Comment: I sincerely hope `$(eventNumber)` is not injected. You should be using parameters